# What are the best resources online for learning the Zohar?

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet, zohar

I ask about online since I travel often so something I can read on my computer would greatly accelerate my learning. I won't complain about recommendations for physical books though! I also want to be careful since there are some texts that appear to be based on Judaism but in fact are not. It's ok if the texts are advanced--I should be ready to handle them.

Comment: not the text of zohar but related articles and books... http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/378725/jewish/Classic-Kabbalah.htm